# Flagging as duplicate answer doesn't recognize short answer URL.

Tags: bug, flags, hyperlinks

I was going through the review queue on Ask Ubuntu and ran across [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13313/where-does-one-get-pretty-screensavers-for-xubuntu-xfce-xscreensaver/256823#256823). It was flagged as a duplicate answer, providing a link to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/256822).

The provided link was in the form:

> `https://askubuntu.com/a/<answer_id>`

After investigating the validity of the flag, I clicked the "flag or disagree" button and entered a custom message that went something like this:

> "Dupe answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/256822"

However, I received an error stating that a post ID or link was required to flag as a duplicate (I forgot to get a screenshot of the error). It seems like the short URL for answers is not recognized.